Are there algorithms for lowering the degree of the polynomials which generate an ideal by strategically adding new variables?
Suppose I have an ideal $I$ in a polynomial ring $F[x_1,...,x_n]$ generated by a few polynomials of maximum degree $k$.
I want to embed the ideal $I$ into a larger ideal $J$ in a larger ring with added variables, say $F[x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1},...x_{m}]$ so that the basis polynomials for $J$ have maximum degree $d<k$ and so that $I$ is an elimination ideal of $J$.
As an example, take $I = \langle x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) \rangle$ in $F[x]$. I can form $J = \langle u^2-u,v^2-v,2v+u-x \rangle$ in $F[u,v,x]$. $I$ is the elimination ideal for $J$, there is a bijection in the underlying varieties, and the maximum degree of the basis polynomials has been reduced from 4 to 2.
Given $I$ there are many choices for $J$, some better than others. I have some heuristics for doing this but an algorithm giving an optimal $J$ escapes me.

Is there a name for what I'm trying to do that I can use for further researching this topic?
Is there an algorithm giving an optimal (or canonical) $J$ for a given degree bound?
Could I take it further and demand more constraints on the generators of $J$ such as number of terms, or number of variables in each generator?


Welcome new contributor.  There is an article by Mumford titled, “Varieties defined by quadratic equations.”  Mumford proves that you can always reduce to two the degrees of all defining equations.

Thank you @JasonStarr. This was helpful for targetting my searches.
